# Clearing TTYACM Buffer C++

Tags: c++, linux, kernel, tty

I have an application which is parsing an incoming stream of IMU data packets. This application streams data intermittently. E.g. upon trigger, start, configure and connect to device. The device then starts streaming data to `/dev/ttyACM0` at a rate of 100hz.

The problem I have, is that if I do not parse these incoming data packets at 100hz continuously, then I read stale data. E.g.

```
int fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
struct termios toptions;
tcgetattr(file_descriptor, &toptions)

//  set default baud rate
cfsetispeed(&toptions, B115200);
cfsetospeed(&toptions, B115200);

toptions.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; //  no parity bit
toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; //  disable 2 stop bits (only one used instead)
toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;  //  disable any previous size settings
toptions.c_cflag |= HUPCL;   //  enable modem disconnect
toptions.c_cflag |= CS8;     //  bytes are 8 bits long

toptions.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; //  no hardware RTS/CTS switch

toptions.c_cflag |=
    CREAD |
    CLOCAL;                                  //  enable receiving of data, forbid control lines (CLOCAL)
toptions.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); //  no software flow control
toptions.c_iflag &= ~(INLCR | ICRNL);        //  disable NL->CR and CR->NL

//  disable the following
//  ICANON = input is read on a per-line basis
//  ECHO/ECHOE = echo enabled
//  ISIG = interrupt signals
toptions.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
toptions.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;           //  disable pre-processing of input data
toptions.c_oflag &= ~(ONLCR | OCRNL); //  disable NL->CR and CR->NL

toptions.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;  //  no minimum number of bytes when reading
toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; //  no time blocking
tcsetattr(file_descriptor, TCSAFLUSH, &toptions)

::write(file_descriptor, &start_cmd.at(0), start_cmd.size());
// Device is now streaming data at 100hz
struct pollfd p;

p.fd = file_descriptor;
p.events = POLLIN;
int r_poll = poll(&p, 1, 100);
// The below reads accurate data
if (r_poll > 0)
    uint read_amount = ::read(file_descriptor, &buffer.at(0), buffer.size());

// Go do something else for a few seconds

// Now the below reads STALE data
if (r_poll > 0)
    uint read_amount = ::read(file_descriptor, &buffer.at(0), buffer.size());
```

So I have determined that there has to be some kernel buffering going on at the ttyACM level as the device does not internally buffer data. I have tried clearing out the read buffer beforehand but this does not seem to solve the issue.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to obtain up-to-date serial data from a TTY ACM device given a latency runaway situation?

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and I am using C++17.